# Is there an easier way to sector an image?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML file with a script that is given a map that has sectors on it. Like A1, B2, but there are sub-sectors, 1-9 in each sector. For example, A1-5, B2-9, etc. As of right now, I have a bunch of IF statements for each sub-sector. Here's an example

```js
if (x > 2093-161/3 && x < 2093 && y < 1932-161*2/3 && y > 1771) {
    var isnumber = "9";
    }
  if (x > 2093-161*2/3 && x < 2093-161/3 && y < 1932-161*2/3 && y > 1771) {
    var  isnumber = "8";
    }
  if (x > 1932 && x < 2093-161*2/3 && y < 1932-161*2/3 && y > 1771) {
    var  isnumber = "7";
    }
  if (x > 2093-161/3 && x < 2093 && y < 1932-161*1/3 && y > 1932-161*2/3) {
    var  isnumber = "6";
    }
  if (x > 2093-161*2/3 && x < 2093-161/3 && y < 1932-161*1/3 && y > 1932-161*2/3) {
    var  isnumber = "5";
    }
  if (x > 1932 && x < 2093-161*2/3 && y < 1932-161*1/3 && y > 1932-161*2/3) {
    var  isnumber = "4";
    }
  if (x > 2093-161/3 && x < 2093 && y < 161*12 && y > 1932-161*1/3) {
    var  isnumber = "3";
    }
  if (x > 2093-161*2/3 && x < 2093-161/3 && y < 161*12 && y > 1932-161*1/3) {
    var  isnumber = "2";
    }
  if (x > 1932 && x < 2093-161*2/3 && y < 161*12 && y > 1932-161*1/3) {
    var  isnumber = "1";
    }
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no simpler easier way.  Note however that you an create image maps of an img using the MAP tag: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: are sectors squares.rectangles with the same size? If so, what is that size?

Comment: You can clearly clean up the code so it does not look so copy and paste heavy. Seems like it could be reduced if the sectors are uniform in dimension. What are the dimensions? I'm too lazy to calculate it here ;)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir On this image, yes. They are 161 pixels. However, I have other images with different sizes.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm making it so that whenever the mouse rolls over the sector and sub-sector, it puts that text next to the mouse. I've got it done, but I'm transitioning to other images, and I don't want to do this all over again.

Comment: @Matt_Mack do we know the size of the sectors of an image in advance? also can you post an image illustrating the dissection of the image?

Comment: @epascarello Dimensions of total image are 5400, but are downscaled to 2160. Each sector is 161 pixels tall and wide, and each sub-sector is 161*1/3.

Comment: this will be easier to understand with an image illustration

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Edit has an example of an image.

Comment: can you also include the second number in the image please? You can only include it for one sector, A1 for example. Is it left-to-right top-to-bottom?

Comment: @ibrahimmahir Yeah, 1-14 down, A-N left to right.

Comment: @Matt_Mack I didn't get that. I'm talking about the subsectors, are they a grid or are they stacked either horizontally or vertically? Please edit the image to include the position of the subsectors aswell

Comment: @ibrahhimmahir Oh, my bad. The start on the bottom left, then go right, then middle left then go right, then top left, then go right. If you have a full keyboard, it looks like the numpad.

Comment: so like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjrSG.jpg ? Also do we know the x and y coordinates of the parent sector beforehand? It will be easier to calculate the number of the subsector if we know `xSector` and `ySector`, the top-left or the bottom-left coordinates of the sector itself

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, like that. Each sector is 161x161pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to get the `x` and `y` coordinates relative to each sector, meaning that we need to convert the coordinates to relative ones that are between `0` and `161`. Like so:

```
var xRelativeToSector = x % 161;
var yRelativeToSector = y % 161;
```

Then we need to convert those relative coordinates into column and row indexes, we have 3 possible columns and 3 possible rows, so:

```
var column = Math.floor(3 * xRelativeToSector / 161);
var row = Math.floor(3 * yRelativeToSector / 161);
```

Finally, we use `column` and `row` to calculate the number using this formula `row * numberOfColumns + column`. Note that the rows in our case are ordered bottom-to-top, so we use `(2 - row)` instead of `row`. We also need to add `1` to the result because the formula gives us a 0-based index and we want a 1-based index. Like so:

```
var isnumber = 3 * (2 - row) + column + 1;
```

So you can simply group this code in a function and use it to get the subsector number:

```
function getSubSectorNumber(x, y) {
    var xRelativeToSector = x % 161;
    var yRelativeToSector = y % 161;

    var column = Math.floor(3 * xRelativeToSector / 161);
    var row = Math.floor(3 * yRelativeToSector / 161);

    return 3 * (2 - row) + column + 1;
}
```

Comment: It's not outputting anything for isnumber. It's just at my default value.

Comment: @Matt_Mack I don't understand what you mean by that? How are you calling the function?

Comment: I copied and edited your example code into my file, however, it's not changing the isnumber variable.


`function getSubSectorNumber(x, y) {
    var xRelativeToSector = x % 161;
    var yRelativeToSector = y % 161;

    var column = Math.floor(3 * xRelativeToSector / 161);
    var row = Math.floor(3 * yRelativeToSector / 161);

    var isnumber = 3 * (2 - row) + column + 1;
}`

Comment: @Matt_Mack but you're not using `isnumber` anywhere. You should call my function when you want to get the subsector number like so: `var text = "A1-" + getSubSectorNumber(x, y);`, in the event listener callback or wherever you had your original code

Comment: That solved it! Thanks for the feedback on this post.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea with Math using division and mod to get the remaining.

```js
var width = 2160;
var sectorW = 161;

function getSector (x) {
   var sectorX = Math.floor(x / sectorW);
   var sub = x - (sectorW * sectorX % x);
   var subSectorX = Math.floor(sub / (sectorW / 3))
   return {
     sectorX: sectorX, 
     subSectorX: subSectorX
   }
}

console.log( 100, getSector(100))
console.log( 180, getSector(180))
```

expanding on it. I am not sure what you real number system looks like... but just playing with it. Below is the basic idea

So a number with `10,10` like `A1 a1`

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|A1         |B1         |C1         |
|  a1 b1 c1 |  a1 b1 c1 |  a1 b1 c1 |
|  a2 b2 c2 |  a2 b2 c2 |  a2 b2 c2 |
|  a3 b3 c3 |  a3 b3 c3 |  a3 b3 c3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|A2         |B2         |C2         |
|  a1 b1 c1 |  a1 b1 c1 |  a1 b1 c1 |
|  a2 b2 c2 |  a2 b2 c2 |  a2 b2 c2 |
|  a3 b3 c3 |  a3 b3 c3 |  a3 b3 c3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|A3         |B3         |C3         |
|  a1 b1 c1 |  a1 b1 c1 |  a1 b1 c1 |
|  a2 b2 c2 |  a2 b2 c2 |  a2 b2 c2 |
|  a3 b3 c3 |  a3 b3 c3 |  a3 b3 c3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

---

```js
var width = 2160;
var sectorW = 161;

function calcalateZone (x) {
   var sectorX = Math.floor(x / sectorW);
   var sub = x - (sectorW * sectorX % x);
   var subSectorX = Math.floor(sub / (sectorW / 3))
   return {
     sector: sectorX, 
     subSector: subSectorX
   }
}

function getLetterCode (v, upper) {
 // use base 36 to get letter code
 var letterCase = upper ? "toUpperCase" : "toLowerCase";
 return (v + 10).toString(36)[letterCase]();
}

function getSector(x, y){
  const coorX = calcalateZone(x);
  const coorY = calcalateZone(y);
  return {
    sector: getLetterCode(coorX.sector, true) + (coorY.sector+1),
    subSector: getLetterCode(coorX.subSector, false) + (coorY.subSector+1)
  }

}

console.log( 100, 100, getSector(100, 100))
console.log( 180, 100, getSector(180, 100))
console.log( 100, 180, getSector(100, 180))
console.log( 180, 180, getSector(180, 180))
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little? I'm a little confused...

Comment: First calculation is how many of the big sectors you can shove into the number. Second calculation is what what value is left when you subtract out the full sectors. Third calulates the sub sector since you broke that up into 3.